# Is it true that $H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)$?

Tags: statistics, information-theory

I have some difficulties with the question

whether $H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)$?

From my knowledge

$I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y) = H(Y)-H(Y|X)$

so

$H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)$

only when

$H(X)=H(Y)$

The question is whether it's the last step, can I make a further assumption about the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ or $H(X)=H(Y)$ is a last step and no further conclusions.

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation  means.  Are you saying that the conditional distribution function of $X$ given $Y=y$ at $x$ is for all values of $x,y$ equal to the conditional distribution function of $Y$ given $X=x$ at $y$?  That seems unlikely.  Presumably I should think of these as density functions or probability mass function, in which case Bayes theorem indeed provides that equality assuming both conditional objects are well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)\iff H(X)=H(Y)$$